# Does the Powerjack give you health when you kill enemies with the flamethrower?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

Does the Powerjack give you health when you kill enemies with the flamethrower? The description isn't very clear.

Comment: This would be too good to be true.

Comment: By the way, what kept you from just trying this???

Comment: As @BlaXpriti confirmed, you only gain health if the kill as made by with the Powerjack. However, this wasn't always the case. Up until the [January 10th patch](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/January_10,_2011_Patch), any kill made while the Powerjack was out would result in gaining health.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: skill

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, The Powerjack does not give you health when you kill enemies with some other weapon.

Comment: Source: tested manually with bots.